# How to make a dialog with content from a string?

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

Is it possible to make a dialog with content from a string defined in your OnCreate? Because the only way to define the content of the dialog, which I could find, is with text or a string defined in values/strings.xml like this:

```
builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles)
```

I hope there is someone who can help me, please tell me if my question is clear enough.

Comment: sorry but i am not getting your question clearly .please give an example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `getString` method of `Context` to get String from strings.xml:

```
builder.setMessage(Your_Activity.this.getString(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
builder.setMessage("Your Message")
```

There are two setMessage() methods, [one for accepting a CharSequence](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setMessage%28java.lang.CharSequence%29), and o[ne for accepting an R.string.*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setMessage%28int%29).

Answer (score 2):

Use getString method

```
ProgressDialog pDialog;

pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.your_xml_string));
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the resources, such as:

```
builder.setMessage(getRessources.getString(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.yourstring);
```

Your activity context give you everything you need to load resources from 'R'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use strings o_O

Check documentation first: [setMessage (CharSequence message)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setMessage%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Then you can check the tutorial test dialog [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog)

And for lazy ones:

```
String text = "Hello";

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(text).setPositiveButton("Wohoo", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // User cancelled the dialog
                }
            });
```

And at the end add this, because you have created dialog and it needs to be show:

```
builder.show();
```